# How to get grouped bar plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization, seaborn

I am new to seaborn and I am trying to plot the bar chart. I am importing data from a csv file. I would like to have the bars small in width and grouped/join for a single category. But, I am getting a lot of spaces between these graphs. Is there a way where I can solve the above problem. Note that my y-axis range is from 80 to 100, and I need to maintain that.

Current code I am using is:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
Data=pd.read_csv('S_Data.csv')
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
ax = sns.barplot(x="Techniques on data", y="Test Accuracy", hue="Epochs",  order = ['WNO + FIFO', 'WNO', 'WNO + on_combined data', 'WNO + replace with gsd'], palette="Blues_d", data=Data)

def change_width(ax, new_value) :
    for patch in ax.patches :
        current_width = patch.get_width()
        diff = current_width - new_value

        # we change the bar width
        patch.set_width(new_value)

        # we recenter the bar
        patch.set_x(patch.get_x() + diff * .5)
change_width(ax, .10)
ax.set_ylim(80,100)
ax.set_title('Result')
```

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you don't use your function to change the width of the bars? How is the result no satisfactory?

Comment: The original plot without changing the width becomes very large in width. This looks better. But want them to get grouped into one category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `countplot` instead of the `barplot` function. [[link]](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html). I believe, based on your `hue="Epochs"`, you will be able to achieve the slimmer bar style without using an additional function.